# How to assemble rook polynomials?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, generating-functions

I have a problem. I need to assemble a rook polynomial for the chessboard (6x6 boards).
Black boards are 1, white boards are 0.

```
                             1 1 1 1 0 0
                             1 1 1 0 0 0
                             1 1 0 0 1 1
                             1 1 0 1 1 1
                             0 0 1 1 1 1
                             0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Can anyone advise me or recommend me some literature, in which these problems are explained in detail? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a reference with detailed explanations, but if you want to quickly check your results, you can use [this rook polynomial calculator.](https://www.bluffton.edu/~nesterd/java/rookpolynomials.html) For the board that you describe above, it gives the rook polynomial $p(x)=1 + 24 x + 203 x^2 + 742 x^3 + 1158 x^4 + 648 x^5 + 76 x^6$ and calculates that only 4 of the 6! permutations will avoid the black squares.